# gspread OAuth 2 json file does not contain client_email or private_key

Tags: json, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to us gspread using OAuth 2. I have seen several people using the code below, however the json file from google developers ("client_secret.....json") does not contain client_email or private_key. Any ideas where I went wrong?

The json file that I have has the following options (not actual these are copied from googles example):

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "asdfjasdljfasdkjf",
    "client_secret": "1912308409123890",
    "redirect_uris": ["www.example/oauth2callback"],
    "auth_uri": "accounts.google/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "accounts.google/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

gspread code I am trying to use:

```
json_key = json.load(open('gspread-test.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Instead of you create an Client ID Oauth 2.0, you must create an Service Account.